# Azure Test Web Chat not working

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I used default code on Azure web app bot, and when I wanted to test the service in the test chat web I received the message below. I did not change anything, and I was using Node.

[image: No page found message]

Answer (score 2):

We are currently investigating the issue, you are not the only one this is affecting.  I will update this answer with updates as we get more information.

**Update 1:54 pm PST**
We have fixed the issue.